# Swiper how to render x next slides

Tags: javascript, next.js, swiper.js

I have been trying to use SwiperJS https://swiperjs.com/, however there seems to be no option that I can find to be able to set that when the slide goes out of view on the left it returns to the right straight away.

Currently it causes this issue, where on the right there is no next slide and it only renders the next slide when it moves.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxQl2.png)

I have tried reviewing all the docs and searching but was unable to find any documentation or examples on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

“*…I can find to be able to set that when the slide goes out of view on the left it `returns` to the right straight away…*”

So you mean `loop`…

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  // other stuff...
});
```